# jQuery, tracking telephone clicks for Google analytics

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

The following code allows me to track telephone click in Analytics but returns clicks for all the elements with the same class shown on the page. I would like to only return a click for the element that is currently clicked. Any suggestions or fixes is greatly appreciated.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
/* Grid telefono */
  jQuery(".ebd-phn-number a").text(function() {
    var buttonText = jQuery(this).text();
    jQuery(this).replaceWith(
      '<a href="tel:1' + 
      jQuery(this)
        .text()
        .replace(/-/g, '')
        .replace(/ /g, '')
        .replace(/\./g, '')
        .replace(/x/g, ',') + 
      '" class="telefono" onclick="' +
      ga(
       'send',
       'event',
       'Phone Call Tracking',
       'Click/Touch',
       buttonText
      ) + '"><span>' + jQuery(this).text() + '</span></a>'
    );
  });   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up removing the onclick from the original javascript and added a click listener with the example on this page. https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/tracking-custom-events-google-analytics.

This was used to track telephone clicks in a Directory that has a grid/list view and a detail view with phone numbers.

```
jQuery(document)
    .ready(function () {
        /* Grid telefono */

        jQuery(".ebd-phn-number a")
            .text(function () {
                jQuery(this)
                    .replaceWith(

                        '<a href="tel:1' + jQuery(this)
                        .text()
                        .replace(/-/g, '')
                        .replace(/ /g, '')
                        .replace(/\./g, '')
                        .replace(/x/g, ',') + '" class="telefono"><span class="ebd-info-value ebd-singl-dtl-phnsc" >' + jQuery(this)
                        .text() + '</span></a>'
                    );
            });


        jQuery('.ebd-phn-number a')
            .click(function () {

                var buttonText = jQuery(this)
                    .text();
                ga('send', 'event', 'Phone Call Grid', 'Click/Touch', buttonText);
            });


    });
```